# How is my python code going out of bound?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception, stringindexoutofbounds

I've been trying to encode a string `(ex: aabbbacc)` to something like `a2b3a1c2`
this is the code i've tried:

```
string_value = "aabbbacc"
temp_string = ""
for i in range(0, len(string_value)):
    if i != len(string_value) or i > len(string_value):
        temp_count = 1
        while string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]:
            temp_count += 1
            i += 1
        temp_string += string_value[i] + str(temp_count)
print(temp_string)
```

the problem is even though I've added an `if` condition to stop out of bounds from happening, I still get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:run_length_encoding.py", line 6, in <module>
    while string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I've also tried

```
string_value = "aabbbacc"
temp_string = ""
for i in range(0, len(string_value)):
    count = 1
    while string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]:
        count += 1
        i += 1
        if i == len(string_value):
            break
    temp_string += string_value[i]+ str(count)
print(temp_string)
```

now, I know there might be a better way to solve this, but I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the out of bounds exception even though i have an if condition to prevent it, at what part of the logic am I going wrong please explain...

Comment: Your issue lies here ```string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]:```

Comment: Think about what happens when `i` is the last value of the string and you do `i+1`.

Comment: More precisely, the issue is that `i != len(string_value) or i > len(string_value)` is always `True`. This does not guard against `i` reaching the last index of the string as you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for i in range(0, len(string_value)): # if i is the last index of the string
    count = 1
    while string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]: # i+1 is now out of bounds
```

The easiest way to avoid out-of-bounds is to not index the strings at all:

```
def encode(s):
    if s == '':   # handle empty string
        return s
    current = s[0]  # start with first character (won't fail since we checked for empty)
    count = 1
    temp = ''
    for c in s[1:]:  # iterate through remaining characters (string slicing won't fail)
        if current == c:
            count += 1
        else: # character changed, output count and reset current character and count
            temp += f'{current}{count}'
            current = c
            count = 1
    temp += f'{current}{count}'  # output last count accumulated
    return temp

print(encode('aabbbacc'))
print(encode(''))
print(encode('a'))
print(encode('abc'))
print(encode('abb'))
```

Output:

```
a2b3a1c2

a1
a1b1c1
a1b2
```

Answer (score 1):

First this check is odd :

```
if i != len(string_value) or i > len(string_value):
```

Second, you check i but read value for i+1, and potentially next...

So my suggestion is to put the condition inside of your while.

And do not allow string_value[i] to be read after you have checked that i==len(string_value).

(I remind you that : "The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.")

Answer (score 1):

Iterate thru each char in the string then check if the next char is the same with current. If yes, then add one else add the count to temp string and reset the count to 1.

```
string_value = "aabbbacc"
temp_string = ""
count = 1
for i in range(len(string_value)-1):
    if string_value[i] == string_value[i+1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        temp_string += string_value[i]+ str(count)
        count = 1

#add the last char count
temp_string += string_value[i+1]+ str(count)

print(temp_string)
Out:  a2b3a1c2
```